# Imported function is not a function react - Shopify app development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify

I am in the process of building a simple Shopify app using the [remix app template](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix). I've managed to set up the prisma schema okay and add some basic data to one of the tables. I now wanted to update the DB based on a checkbox being toggled. So for instance, checkbox toggle runs a function, updates DB and the updates state.

Here is the code that runs the import

```
import { getDelivery } from "../models/delivery.server";
import { updateDelivery } from "../models/delivery.server";
```

Here is the action function ran on checkbox tick

```
export async function action({request}) {

  const deliveryDetails = await updateDelivery(Number(1));

};
```

Here is the updateDelivery function loaded from the delivery.server.js file

```
import db from "../db.server";


export async function getDelivery(id) {
    console.log("got to this function")
    const deliveryDetails = await db.deliveryDate.findFirst({ where: { id } });
  
    if (!deliveryDetails) {
      return null;
    } else {
        console.log("hit the return delivery")
        console.log(deliveryDetails)
        return deliveryDetails;
    }
  
   
  }

  export async function updateDelivery(id) {

    console.log("hit the update function")
    const data = {
    "shop": "Test",
      "deliveryOn": false
      
    }
    const deliveryDetails =  await db.deliveryDate.update({ where: { id: id }, data });

    if (!deliveryDetails) {
        return null;
      } else {
          console.log("hit the update delivery")
          console.log(deliveryDetails)
          return deliveryDetails;
      }
   
  
  };
```

Here is how I call it

```
 <Checkbox
                        label="Add delivery box to UI"
                        checked={checked}
                        onChange={action}
                        />
```

So onchange should call action which in turn hits the update delivery function, it should update DB with updated details. However it when it hits the action function I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , import_delivery2.updateDelivery) is not a function
```

What I don't understand is why the getDelivery function fires fine and returns the initial data but the update won't work.